# Load DropDownList from Database, then get the Value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2016

I'm not sure how ASP.NET works since I'm still very new to it, coming from a PHP background where most things are done with POST. I'm using VB.NET behind the code. Mainly because the main program used here is written in VB.NET and I want to keep the code portable without compiling a library.

My issue is as follows. I have a DropDownList on the page. I populate it with data from the database. That seems to work fine.

I have a button that should change the CLIENTCODE to whatever has been selected in the DropDownBox. This doesn't work. Instead the Index is always -1.

Page Code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" CodeBehind="Admin.aspx.vb" Inherits="WOTC_CP.Admin" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="RightBody" runat="server">
   <% 
       Load_UserList_List()
%>
<h1 class="sub-header">Administration Toolbox</h1>
<p>If you are not an Administrator, please send us an alert and leave this page at once.</p>
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">Change my Clientcode;</asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboClientList" class="form-control" runat="server" >

            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:Button ID="cmdChangeClientCode" class="btn btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Change"  />


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Behind Code

```
Public Sub Load_CLIENTCODE_List()
    If IsPostBack = False Then
        Using DB As New wotcDB
            Dim r = (From t In DB.client_main Order By t.CLIENTCODE Select t.CLIENTCODE).Distinct
            For Each Client In r
                Dim input As New ListItem
                input.Text = Client
                input.Value = Client
                cboClientList.Items.Add(input)
            Next
        End Using
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub cmdChangeClientCode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdChangeClientCode.Click
    Dim CLIENTCODE As String = CType(Session("CLIENTCODE"), String)
    Dim UserName As String = CType(Session("UserName"), String)
    Using DB As New wotcDB
        Dim u = (From t In DB.website_users Where t.UserName = UserName).FirstOrDefault
        If u IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim TempID As Integer = cboClientList.SelectedIndex
            Dim TempValue As String = cboClientList.SelectedValue
            u.CLIENTCODE = cboClientList.SelectedValue
            DB.SaveChanges()
        End If
    End Using
End Sub
```

I've tried other answers here on stack, but nothing seems to work. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net the dropdown list has two key properties that you want to set. DataTextField = Display Name and DataValueField = value to store to DB. 
With that said, you need to capture the "SelectedValue" if you want to get the DataValueField.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was loading the script that populated the DropDownList before getting it's value. So it was always empty. The solution was to load the list on Page_Load instead.